# Prove that this is a metric using the definition

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $\Omega:=\{x=(x_{n})\in \ell^{2}| \phantom{x} \|x\|\leq 1\}$. Consider $d:\Omega\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ defined by 
>   $$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|.$$
>   Prove that $d$ is a metric on $\Omega$.

I have two questions.
What I have done so far:

Firstly we prove symmetry. We have

\begin{align*}
d(x,y) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|(-1)(y_{n}-x_{n})| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|y_{n}-x_{n}| = d(y,x).
\end{align*}

Secondly we prove the triangle inequality. We have

\begin{align*}
d(x,y) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-y_{n}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-z_{n}+z_{n}-y_{n}| \\
 &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}(|x_{n}-z_{n}|+|z_{n}-y_{n}|) \\
 &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-z_{n}|+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|z_{n}-y_{n}| =d(x,z)+d(y,z).
\end{align*}

Finally we prove the definiteness. If $x=y$ then we have

$$d(x,y)=d(x,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-x_{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\cdot 0=0,$$

and if $d(x,y)=0$ then we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|=0 $$

(Question 1: What do I do know to conclude that $x=y$? Just say $x_{n}-y_{n}=0 \Rightarrow x_{n}=y_{n} \Rightarrow x=y$?)

Thus $d$ is a metric on $\Omega$. (Question 2: Have I shown it correctly? Struggled the most with the definiteness)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Your proofs are right. About definiteness : for all $n$ you have $2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n| =0$ and then for all $n$ $2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|=0$. But I think you missed one point : why is the serie correctly defined ? You have an infinite sum and it is not obvious that $d(x,y)$ is correctly defined for all $x$ $y$

Comment: looks good to me too . :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it as an answer to highlight the point :

In this kind of problem (showing that something is a distance), you have two points to prove :

1. The first one is the trap (and you didn't talk about it) : you have to show that $d(x,y)$ is correctly defined on the space you are working on (here $\Omega$).

Here you have to use Cauchy Schwarz inequality :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|\leq \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}(|x_n|+|y_n|)\leq \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}|x_n| +\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}|y_n|$$
And 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n 4^{-n}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |x_n|^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n 4^{-n}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n |y_n|^2}$$

And because $x$ and $y$ are in $\Omega$ :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|\leq ||x||_2\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-n}}+||y||_2\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-n}}$$

2.Only then you can use your proofs to show that the function has the properties of a distance.

Comment: can't you simply use the $\infty$ sign instead of n in the sum with these inequalities. And aren't some inequalities here equalities?

Comment: To show that it is well defined, because it is a sum of non negative term, you just have to show that the partial sum have an upper bound. About using $\infty$ instead of $n$, this is precisely my point : before taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ you have to show that the limit exists ! And equality or not you just want to get the upper bound.